# Why am I getting the swift error “Argument passed to call that takes no arguments”

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have narrowed down the problem to this part:

```
init () { 
  UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue
}
```

but I don’t know why this line is causing it. If I remove this line the error disappears.

The error is on the line:

```
PrimaryView(j: i)
```

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var i = "hi"
    var body: some View {
        PrimaryView(j: i)
    }
}

struct PrimaryView: View {
    init () {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue
    }
    var j = String()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have explicitly defined `init` for `PrimaryView` as `init()` -- ie, it takes no arguments. If you want to pass in something for `j`, you'll have to do that by hand.

```
struct PrimaryView: View {
    var j = String()
    init (j: String) {
        self.j = j
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Swift does a lot of work synthesizing initializers of `struct`s for us, making it easy to pass in parameters. But, if you override, `init`, you're forced to write the initializer parameters yourself.

Comment: How would I do this if I was binding and j was @State?